# Direct2D drawing arc missing pixels and irritating antialiasing

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, delphi, direct2d

When drawing arcs with pathgeometry and arc segments in d2d there are some glitches compared to other frameworks. I have created a zoomed version from a arc drawn with d2d and with wpf [wpf vs d2d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELPCp.png). I have marked the areas which are imho not drawn correctly in direct2d. Does somebody know what caused such drawings?

Sample code (SharpDX):

```
private static void TestRender(WindowRenderTarget renderTarget)
{
    var geo = new PathGeometry(d2dFactory);
    var sink = geo.Open();

    Vector2 off = new Vector2(40.0f, 70.0f);
    var arc_1 = new ArcSegment()
    {
        ArcSize = ArcSize.Small,
        RotationAngle = 0,
        Point = off,
        Size = new Size2F(22, 22),
        SweepDirection = SweepDirection.CounterClockwise
    };

    sink.BeginFigure(new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawVector2(84, 70), FigureBegin.Filled);
    sink.AddArc(arc_1);
    sink.EndFigure(FigureEnd.Open);

    sink.Close();

    StrokeStyle strokeStyle = new StrokeStyle(d2dFactory, new StrokeStyleProperties()
    {
        DashCap = CapStyle.Flat,
        DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid,
        LineJoin = LineJoin.Miter,
        StartCap = CapStyle.Flat,
        EndCap = CapStyle.Flat,
        MiterLimit = 0,
        DashOffset = 0
    }, new float[0]);

    var testBrush = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.SolidColorBrush(
        renderTarget,
        new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawColor4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        new SharpDX.Direct2D1.BrushProperties
        {
            Opacity = 1.0f,
        }
    );

    renderTarget.DrawGeometry(geo, testBrush, 10, strokeStyle);
    geo.Dispose();
    sink.Dispose();

}
```

After digging a bit i have found that if i shift the starting point a half "pixel" in the y direction everything looks good. Question for me is now how to programmaticaly determine which coordinates needs to be transformed.
Furthermore i wonder how wpf is doing this. I know about UseLayoutRounding and SnapToPixels. I'm interested how they (MS) are doing that for the various shapes.

Comment: An example snippet of your code might be helpful here.

Comment: does setting ``EdgeMode.Aliased`` in  ``RenderOptions`` works?

Comment: @Ramin: EdgeMode is from wpf? I use sharpDX. But i could also reproduce the same with a simple delphi application.

Comment: @soeren.dd: half pixel shifts you're seeing are normal, WPF/D2D is using fractional coordinates, that could be snapped or not. Think of it as if 0.0 position was exactly at the left edge of a pixel, and at the right edge of the preceding it (talking X direction). When you fill this pixel with some color, half of pixel at -1 and half of 0 one are filled. Which in case of AA obviously results in blending.

Comment: @bunglehead: Thank you for your explanations. I'm now aware of that half pixel shifting but have problems to correctly determine when i have to shift which coordinate. It seems that it should be possible to do it in an generic way because wpf does it.

Comment: @soeren.dd: you can simply round arc control points to half pixel, don't know what's delphi equivalent would be, in C it will looks something like coord_x = floorf(coord_x) + 0.5f.

Comment: @bunglehead: thanks for the hint. But this is what i already found out. The problem is that i have to do this with the startpoint of the geometry (BeginFigure). In the case the arc is horizontal as shown in the image i have to use the y coordinate and in case of a vertical arc i have to use x. The problem for me is that i cant know in advance if a arc is in the figure. Furthermore the endpoint of a line could be the startpoint of the arc

Comment: @soeren.dd" well, sure. It obviously applies to both coordinates. Can you snap all control points regardless of figure type to half pixel?

Comment: @bunglehead: No this wont work. If I add a half unit to every x and y i get the very same output. Furthermore the arc is sometimes not 180 degree (a bit more or less than 180 degree)